# Unable/remove last login information from MOTD when login using a shell into Linux /Slackware 13.37/

Tags: linux, slackware, motd

I am configuring a Linux machine(Slackware 13.37) which should print some instructions right after user login. The user will login using a shell (keyboard and monitor connected directly with the Linux machine,**not SSH**) and I want to remove **Last Login Info**

 I have edited **/etc/ssh/sshd_config -> PrintLastLog no** 

Unfortunately it works only for SSH logins.
I don't want to use ~.hushlogin, because I need to print some messages on the screen, but I want to remove the last login info.
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Not sure if PrintLastLog can be silenced, but you should be looking in `/etc/login.defs` not `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Hey @Abc Xyz , Thank you. You had helped a lot. I managed to configure it  after editing of `/etc/login.defs`

Comment: Could you tell which option is responsible for silencing last login information?